# Representation of positive rational numbers as series.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

So, in my introductory course on calculus my professor formulated this problem:
Prove: Every positive rational number can be written uniquely as:
$$a_1+\frac{a_2}{2!}+\frac{a_3}{3!}+\dots+\frac{a_n}{n!}$$
with $n\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $0\le a_k\lt k$ for $k\in\{2,\dots,n\}$ and $a_n\neq0$.

Now we recently introduced limits, sequences and series after we constructed $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. The whole expression looks similar to the power series of the exponential function but I am completely lost in figuring out why this would be a valid representation for positive rational numbers. I would be really glad if someone could give me a hint or point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's not directly related to the power series for $e^x$. It's more like a "base" notation for numbers in which the base varies. Probably best to ignore the "limits" issue, since this is finite sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like the base $b$ notation for a number, but with the base varying per digit.

For example: 
$$
\begin{align}\frac{17}{10} &= 1 + \frac{7}{10} \\&=1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{5} \\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2!} +\frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{30}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{4}{5!}
\end{align}$$

If  $x$ is a real number, define the sequence $$x_1=x\\a_i=\lfloor x_i\rfloor\\x_{i+1}=(i+1)(x_i-a_i)$$
Then:
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{i!}$$

This sum  will terminate when $x$ was rational - that is $x_n=0$ for some $n$, and so $a_i=0$ for $i\geq n$.

Since $0\leq x_i-a_i<1$, we have that $0\leq x_{i+1}<i+1$ and thus $0\leq a_{i+1}<i+1$.

More generally, if $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n,\dots\}$ is a sequence of natural numbers all greater than $1$, then we can define $B_0=1$, $B_{n}=b_nB_{n-1}$ and write any real number as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_i}{B_i}$$ with $a_i$ integers and, for $i>0$, $0\leq a_i<b_i$.

When the $b_i=b$, this is the base $b$ representation. When $b_i=i+1$, this is the representation above.

Given a rational number $x$ such that $xB_n$ is an integer for some $n$, then $x$ can be written as a finite sum in the above format.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you for the clear explanation

Comment: Could you explain how you made the series split: $\frac{7}{10} \to \frac12 + \frac15?$

Comment: How would you add $\frac{1}{2}+\frac15,$ @Buraian

Comment: I mean yeah it is simple to go in reverse, but I am trying to figure out how you figured out how to split it succesively like how was it concluded to go $ \frac15 \to \frac{1}{3!}+ \frac{1}{30}$

Comment: In general, pick the largest coefficient $a_n\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ so that $$\frac{a_n}{n!}<x-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{i!}.$$ This is how you find the digits base $10,$ except then $a_n$ is always from $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and $$\frac{a_n}{10^n}<x-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_i}{10^i}.$$ In both cases, $a_0=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and can always show that the difference on the right side is $<\frac n{n!}$ or $<\frac{10}{10^n},$ respectively. @Buraian

Comment: More generally, given a sequence of integer $b_1,b_2,\dots$ of integers all greater than $1,$ and $c_0=1,c_n=b_1b_2\cdots b_n,$ we can compute “digits” for real $x$ as $a_0=\lfloor x\rfloor,$ and picking the maximum  $a_{n}\in\{0,1,\dots,b_n-1\}$ so that $$\frac{a_n}{c_n}\leq x-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{c_i}.$$ When all the $b_i$ are equal, this is the base $b=b_1$ expansion of $x.$ When $b_k=k$ for all $k,$ we violate the rule $b_1>1,$ but then $a_1=0$ always, so we can pretend it isn’t there. @Buraian

Comment: You can show that the representation is unique if and only if $c_n/c_{n-1}$ is an integer for all $n$.

Comment: I read your comment multipile times but I still don't understand, could you explain how to get digits in base 10 example explicitly pls @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Sorry, but that would be really inappropriate for comments. Comments are not good for detailed arguments. @Buraian

Comment: What was your motivation behind defining the sequence? What was the thought process?