# Prove that $x = a_1+\dfrac{a_2}{2!}+\dfrac{a_3}{3!}+\cdots$

Tags: number-theory

> If $x$ is a positive rational number, show that $x$ can be uniquely expressed in the form $$x = a_1+\dfrac{a_2}{2!}+\dfrac{a_3}{3!}+\cdots\text{,}$$ where $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are integers, $0 \leq a_n \leq n-1$ for $n > 1$, and the series terminates.

I don't see how in the solution below we can take "$a_n \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $m - a_n = nm_1$ for some $m_1$".

**Book's solution:**

[image]

Comment: You want $a_n \equiv m \pmod{n}$. And $\{0,1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How do we know that for the particular rational number $\dfrac{m}{n!}$ we have that $a_n \equiv m \pmod{n}$?

Comment: We _choose_ $a_n$ so that the congruence holds.

Comment: @DanielFischer They say we are given a rational number $\dfrac{m}{n!}$ and so $a_n$ is unique, so we can't just pick $a_n$.

Comment: There is one and only one $k \in \{0,1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ such that $k \equiv m \pmod{n}$. If we take $a_n = k$, then we get a representation by the induction hypothesis. That proves the existence of a choice of $a_n$ that works. And if we have a representation of the given form, then it follows that $a_n \equiv m \pmod{n}$. That shows the uniqueness of the choice.

Comment: It's nothing more than the archimedian principal.  We have m and n so we can find m = kn + a where k , a are natural numbers (including 0) and a is less than n.  So $a_n = a$ and $m_n= k$.  For instance.  If we had 27/6! we'd have 27 = 4*6 + 3 and we'd choose $a_6 = 3$ and $m_6=4$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why do they mention the "On the other hand" part? Didn't we already show $a_n$ is unique?

Comment: No. The first part just shows "If we take $a_n \equiv m \pmod{n}$, then we get a representation of the desired form". So far, it is conceivable that also some other choices for $a_n$ could lead to a representation.

Comment: @DanielFischer There was another part to this question, which was to "Show also that $x$ can be expressed as a sum of reciprocals of different integers each of which is greater than $10^6$." They said "Now since $a_i | i!$ and $\dfrac{i!}{a_i} > (i-1)! \geq \dfrac{(i-1)!}{a_{i-1}}$, we see that each rational $q$, $0 < q < 1$ can be written as the sum of different reciprocals. " How is this claim true?

Comment: I hope they mentioned the problem you get when $a_i=0$. By $18$, we can write $q\in(0,1)$ as $$q= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{a_k}{k!}$$ for some $n$, where $a_k\in \{0,1,\dotsc,k-1\}$. Dropping the terms with $a_k=0$, we get $$q=\sum_{\mu=1}^m \frac{a_{k_\mu}}{k_\mu!}$$ with $a_{k_\mu}\in\{1,2,\dotsc, k_\mu-1\}$ and $k_\mu<k_{\mu+1}$ for all $1 \leqslant \mu < m$. Since $r\mid k!$ for all $1 \leqslant r \leqslant k-1$, $c_\mu := \frac{k_\mu!}{a_{k_\mu}}$ is an integer. And since $1\leqslant a_{k_\mu} < k_\mu$, we have $k_\mu! \geqslant c_\mu > \frac{k_\mu!}{k_\mu} = (k_\mu-1)!$. So $c_\mu<c_{\mu+1}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Representation of positive rational numbers as series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905034/representation-of-positive-rational-numbers-as-series)

Answer (score 0):

It's the archmedian principal.  For any two natural number $m$ and $n$ there exist a unique natural number (including 0) $k$ such that $k*n \le m < (k+1)n$.

Or in other words for any two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ there are unique natural $k$ and $a$ such that $m = k*n + a; 0\le a < n$.

Or in other words for any two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ there are unique $m-a = k*n$.

Or in other words for any $m/n!$ we can choice $a_n$ to be the unique $a_n \in \{0,..... ,n-1\}$ so that $m - a_n = n*m_1$ for some natural $m_1$.  (i.e. $a_n = a$ above and $m_1 = k$ above.)