# Induction validity checking in the proof for the below fact regarding a rational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Prove that $x = a_1+\dfrac{a_2}{2!}+\dfrac{a_3}{3!}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1792136/1021792).

1. In the books solution given there , how did they assume any rational $\frac{p}{q}$ to be of form $\frac{m}{n!}$ , although it seems pretty obvious from just example consideration ,but what would be the accurate proof of that fact ? ( My way was we can always multiply denomiator and numerator with same number ) but i dont think it would be called a proper proof .
2. Also in the proof of first step of the induction step they called its trivial , but infact it uses the fact that all terms of a2/2 , a_3/3! all are not integers and all are summing giving a real number below 1 right ? Otherwise it would not be a unique representation .
3. Also in the **assumption step of induction** why they treat that $\frac{m}{(n-1)!}$ can be expressed as in form of $a1+ ....\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1!}$ , why not more terms like upto ..$\frac{a_z}{z!}$ where z can be greater than n-1 ?

Comment: $(1)\  $ Put $\,Q=n!\,$ in **Lemma:** $\ \color{#c00}{q\mid Q}\,\Rightarrow\, \dfrac{p}q\,$ is writable with denom $Q.\ $ **Proof:** $\ \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{p\:\!\color{#c00}{Q/q}}{Q}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque i understood what about the rest two ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n!=n((n-1)!)$. Hence $$\frac mn=\frac{m(n-1)!}{n!}.$$

Comment: Yeah Sir that i understood for the other two parts ?