# Can an integer be expressed as a sum of numbers that are a divisor of its factorial?

Tags: number-theory

*Prove that every natural number between $1$ and $n!$ can be expressed as a sum of at most $n$ natural numbers, all of which divide $n!$.*

Here are my steps:

Let us have a set, $A$, which denotes all possible numbers between $1$ and $n!$:

$$A=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n,n+1,\dots,n!\}$$

Let us have a set, $B$, which includes some numbers that divide $n!$ (by the definition of factorial):

$$B=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n\}$$

The definitive list of all number that divide $n!$ would be
$$\mathcal{P}(B)$$
where each subset would be a result of multiplication of its members.

Every natural number $k\in A$ must be able to be expressed as a sum of some numbers in $B$ (and also some of their multiplies).

If our number $k$ is between $1$ and $n$, it automatically divides $n!$, so this case is trivial.

If it is, however, harder for cases where $n<k\le n!$. How would one go about proving this part of the proof?

Please, I don't want to miss the fun of figuring this out, I only want a push to the right direction.

Comment: I would aim for the smallest number from $1$ to $n!$ which cannot be found this way, and then show it cannot be $\ge \frac{n!}2$ or $\ge \frac{n!}3$ or $\ge\cdots$ because if there is  such a number then there will be a smaller one.  You may want to consider whether successive divisors of $n!$ can have a  ratio greater than $2$

Comment: Hello @Henry, thank you for your answer! Does your way lead to a proof by contradiction? I don't think I follow.

Comment: Yes - the aim is to show that there is no smallest number $\le n!$ that cannot be found this way, and therefore all numbers up to $n!$ can  be found this way

Comment: The thing to do is find explicit summations when $n=3,$   then $n=4$  say... Learn how the problem works

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $n \ge 2$, prove (e.g., by using posts like [Representation of positive rational numbers as series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905034/602049)) that, for each integer $1 \le k \lt n!$, there exist integers $0 \le a_i \lt i$ for $2 \le i \le n$ (note they're actually unique for each $k$, but this isn't needed for your problem) such that

$$\frac{k}{n!} = \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{a_i}{i!}$$